# Save multiple selection sets in QGIS

Tags: qgis, tools, select-by-attribute

I'm looking for a feature in QGIS but I am not sure if it exists.
I don't know the name of such feature, but I call it multiple selection sets. It exists in TransCAD and I find it very useful. It basically allows one to save the selected features under a name, and have multiple sets that one can compose (union, intersection, difference, etc).
I am under the impression that QGIS allows only to save the selected set as a new file, which is not what I am looking for.
Does it exists in QGIS? How can one use it? If not, is there a work-around?

Comment: Still looking for this feature.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1 - New Memory Layer plugin**

With some steps, you can create a memory layer from your selection.

1. Install [New Memory Layer plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/NewMemoryLayer/);
2. Add a new memory layer into your project in Layer > New > New Memory Layer;
3. Select the same geometry type and CRS as your original layer;
4. Make your original layer active, create your desired selection and copy the features (Edit > copy features or CTRL+C);
5. Make your memory layer active and editable;
6. Add the necessary new attributes with the same name and type as the original layer
7. Paste the features (Edit > paste features or CTRL+V)

**Method 2 - Using Processing toolbox (> QGIS 2.2)**

Using processing toolbox, this is pretty straightforward.

1. Make your original layer active, create your desired selection;
2. If it's not yet done, open Processing toolbox in Processing >  Toolbox;
3. Find the "Save selected features (QGIS algorithms > Vector general tools);
4. Use your original layer as input and leave the "Save as temporary layer" as output.

**Note:** Beware that all temporary or memory layers will be lost if the project is closed. So make sure to save them before you do.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming all the features are in one layer, you could add another column/attribute which can be a flag to say some features are grouped. To visually create a group, select them with the various tools, then using the plugin QuickMultiAttributeEdit (which you installed earlier) you hit F12 and update the flag attribute to 1 to indicate the group.

Then you can carry out processing tasks according to the groups.

Otherwise, you need to consider the organisation of your data, layers, shapefiles etc. Without more detail my suggestions are limited to the above.

Comment: Thanks, but that's pretty much the same as saying I don't need selection at all, I can just add a new column an go flagging around. The whole point of selection sets is being very  easy to use, and I find creating new columns very cumbersome

Comment: Work-arounds tend to be cumbersome I guess.